# How to reset state when navigating away from page

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a map that triggers a modal when I click on a marker. The modal is a touchable which navigates to another page. When the page is dismissed and the user returns to the Home page (in this case), it is not possible to touch another marker and trigger a new modal. Any idea how I should set this up so that it is reset when navigating back to home? Some code below:

constants in my functional component that set state:

```
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(false);

  const markerPressed = (marker) => {
    setModalVisible(true);
    setSelectedMarker(marker);
  };
  const markerLink = (selectedMarker) => {
    setModalVisible(false);
    onPressListingItem(selectedMarker);
  };
```

The marker with the param to trigger modal:

```
             <CustomMarker
                onPress={() => {
                  markerPressed(listing);
                }}
              />
```

The modal with param to navigate to page:

```
 <Modal
          style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 10 }}
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
          setModalVisiblity={() => {
            setModalVisible((preState) => (preState = !preState));
          }}>
```

Comment: Just unmount the map component, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: You could reset the data in the same place you trigger your Modal, in your markerPressed function. That way when you return, the data would be reset.

Solution 2: If you are using react-navigation, you could add a focus listener to check when your mp page comes back into focus.

```
navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    // reset marker state
});
```